# How to install typo3/cms-workspaces extension via composer in TYPO3 V9

Tags: composer-php, workspace, typo3-9.x

I have a TYPO3 V9 LTS installed via composer (as recommended in the tutorial), which working fine so far. Now I want to install the "workspaces" extension. This must be done via composer, too.

```
$ composer require typo3/cms-workspaces
```

All console lines are green, no errors occured, seems fine. 
But after login to the TYPO3 backend, the following error message appeared:

> Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\TableNotFoundException
>
> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT `uid`, `title`,
>   `adminusers`, `members` FROM `sys_workspace` WHERE
>   (`sys_workspace`.`deleted` = 0) AND (`sys_workspace`.`pid` = 0) ORDER
>   BY `title` ASC': Table 'typo3_v9_testserver.sys_workspace' doesn't
>   exist

I assume that composer didn't the same way to install an extension as the conventional TYPO3 backend would do (especial here create or extense DB tables). How to install the "workspaces" extension via composer?

Comment: if the extension exists then go to the install tool and click on the current table structure. Removing cache would be helpful too but not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: 
Go to install tool  (thanks to Aristeidis Karavas for comment above)

```
https://mytypo.com/typo3/install.php
```

Go to Maintenance -> "Analyse Database Structure".
There are a lot of `CREATE TABLE` statements.
Click on "Apply selected changes".